# wp-login not found - All usual solutions not working

Tags: wp-admin, login, 404-error, 500-internal-error

A new client of me can't login to his old(er) Wordpress website: wp-login gives a 404 error and wp-admin gives a 500 error.

Here are the links (removed)

I came across this issue before, but this time nothing seems to help. What I have tried so far (one by one so they don't affect eachother):

- rename plugins-folder through ftp
- rename active theme folder through ftp
- rename .htaccess file
- added the following lines of code to wp-config.php:

  define('WP_HOME','https://###');
  define('WP_SITEURL','https://###');

I have searched around for other possible fixes, but haven't found anything. Anyone knows what else i can do?

Comment: hi i help you please debug true in wp-config.php file and check error and message me

Comment: A 500 error is an internal server error. This error may be due to a script error or misconfiguration of your web hosting. It is not necessarily the hosting is responsible but surely, in any case, this error can be resolved by you.

Comment: please check folder permission  and add wp-config file                                       
     define ('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '300M');

Comment: `/wp-login/` is not correct. It's `/wp-login.php`. Granted, you'd just get a 500 error if you logged in, but that's why you're getting a 404.

Answer (score 1):

yourdomainname/wp-login (Wrong) -- 404 or NOT FOUND
yourdomainname/wp-login.php (Correct) --> you will redirect to page login
yourdomainname/wp-admin (Correct) --> you will redirect to page login:
[image]

---
Note:
Make sure your site has SSL installed so that it can be accessed with `httpS`. If not, try with `http` (only)
---
Please open your Hosting, go to `public_html` directory. Open `error_log`to see the reason for error **500**. Then paste the error in the question. This will make it easier for the answerer to find the exact problem
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If issue still not solved,After trying all the options given by all then you may try to check the folder structure of wp-includes and wp-admins.
Check all the file with wordpress core file.
There might be some file deleted.